# Query string not passing correctly to Controller using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two textboxes

```
  <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
  <input type="text" id="txt2"/>
```

and a button

```
  <input type="submit" value="update" name="btn" id="update"/>
```

Here I want to pass textboxes text to controller action method, for that i have written script like below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#update").click(function () {
            var text1=$("#txt1").val();
            var text2=$("#txt2").val();
             location.href = '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Employer")?empid=' + empid + '&&startdate='+text1+'&&enddate='+txt2;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and passing to query string values to  Controller.

```
        public ActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(string btn, TimesheetModel timesheetModel,[Optional]string text1,[Optional]string txt2 )

        //Not Getting passed values of txt1 and txt2 from jquery, when script enter to here, getting null value instead of data.
       {
          //some code here
       }
```

please help me anyone.

Comment: where is timesheetModel data in ur jquery??

Comment: I have set as Optional, sorry i didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

QueryString notition in .net is name convention. 
Solution :change your server side values names for example:
`text1` should change to `startdate` :

```
public ActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(string empid,[Optional]string startdate,[Optional]string enddate, TimesheetModel timesheetModel=null )
```

And 1 more thing you should send only one & in your query string not two:

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Employer")?empid=' + empid + '&startdate='+text1+'&enddate='+txt2;
```

. 
anyway the model can not pass on a get request so this should be removed or change the request to post instead.

Comment: so, What is the solution for this, i need to send both values

Answer (score 0):

Change your action result to this,

```
  public ActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(string empid, string startdate, string enddate)
  {
      // Your code......      
  }
```